# A problem with a ListBox's template

Tags: c#, wpf

I changed the template of the ListBox. The problem is, look at the vertical Scrollbar:
http://img223.imageshack.us/img223/3391/lisbox.jpg

how to make it lie within ths rounded ListBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your wanting the scrollbar more left

> make it lie within ths rounded ListBox

Then add a margin to your ScrollViewer section of the ListBox template like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Focusable="false"  Margin="0,0,20,0">
    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If you want the background of the ScrollViewer to match the ListBox background you'll need to replace the Style template for this also.

```
<ScrollViewer Focusable="false"  Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}" >
    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```